# Which is correct? I suggest he practise for the upcoming test OR I suggest that he practises for the upcoming test?

Tags: phrase-usage

I have written school reports for several years and recently, a colleague has said a verb like recommend or suggest must be followed by that and the second verb conjugated to the pronoun it refers to.
For example, I wrote, 'I recommend he run for at least 2 hours a day'. However, I have now been told it must be, ' I recommend that he runs for at least 2 hours a day'. Another one is below.

Which is correct? I suggest he practise for the upcoming test OR I suggest that he practises for the upcoming test?
Can someone please shed some light on this for me.
Thank you in anticipation that both forms are correct.

Comment: Try searching on this site, or elsewhere, for the rules of the English subjunctive mood.

Comment: You are correct; your colleague is wrong.  I would call the complement sentence an embedded imperative (rather than a subjunctive).